# Vertical-align <span> or <div>

Tags: jquery, css, animation, vertical-alignment

I need to center some text inside a `<div>` or `<span>` tag.
I've set the `display:table-cell`. That worked.
But I want to animate it (using jQuery). But this doesn't work because the display is set back to `display:block`. I don't want that, because that's not displaying properly.

Does anyone know a way to do it?

(Tell me if you need the code I used.)

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li id="1">
    <span id="spanimg1">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <img id="img1" src="1.jpg" />        
</li>
<li id="2">
    <span id="spanimg2">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <img id="img2" src="2.jpg"/>        
</li>
<li id="3">
    <span id="spanimg3">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <img id="img3" src="3.jpg"/>        
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<style>
#container {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position:relative;
margin: auto;
vertical-align:middle;
}

li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type:none;
}
li span {
position:relative;
background:black;
width:400px;
height:80px;
text-align:center;
color:white;
display:none;
z-index:1000;
vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
position:absolute;
display:none;
}
.showimg {
display:block;
}
.show {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes please post source code/mark up and related CSS

Comment: Of course we need the bloody code. Please provide.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is quite useful for posting up code.

Comment: There's the Code :)
There is maybe some extra CSS that's not important. But that's because i'm playing with it for 2 days now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to jQuery 1.4.3 or later got get support for `table-cell` display in animations.

Comment: Well i've got the latest jQuery code "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js", until now it doesn't work...
But i'm rewriting the code now! :) Hopefully that works :)

Comment: @Milaan: I assume the issue is with the `span` where you have `display:none`. Is that right? If so, you'll have issues because jQuery won't know what the default should be, so it will assume `block`. Instead, try giving the specific `span` elements you're talking about class names that represent `display:none` and `display:table-cell`. Then use `addClass` and `removeClass` to update the style.

Comment: It works perfectly. But i have one problem. When the animation adds the class "show" then it works. But it doesn't work when I give the SPAN element an "Absolute"-positioning. Well, it works, but then everything in the span isn't centered anymore. It does work with relative but then my other content goes down too (and that's not what supposed to happen) :)
I hope you get what i mean?
Do you know anything to fix that? :$

Comment: @Milaan: I'd need to see your actual HTML/CSS at this point to know for sure, but try giving the elements that are content of the span `margin: 0 auto;` to center them.

Comment: I added it in the first post :) I have a jQuery script that assigns the "show" to the span elements. But couldn't I also just have the SPAN elements with "display:table-cell" and then use jQuery to HIDE() everything onload. Then I dont have to assign the "show"-class but I only have to "slideDown", roght?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I can see now that you posted your code that you have fixed heights. Just add this to your "li span" tag and it should center all text vertically.

```
line-height: 80px;
```

Comment: Yes but that's for only one line of text, not for multiple lines... If i'm not mistaken

Comment: Sorry, could you post an example how you got it work with table-cell displays so I can see what you are trying to go for?

Comment: Thanks for your time! The anser above works perfectly! But I appreciate the time you took to answer!